# Зависимый от параметра шаблона false

Tags: c++, c++11

Есть шаблонная структура у которой допускается использовать только специализации. Естествеенно `static_assert(false, "You must use specialization!");` не сработает, потому что `false` не зависит от параметров шаблона.

Решается просто:

```
template<class T>
struct AlwaysFalse : std::false_type{};

template<class T>
struct Foo{
    static_assert(AlwaysFalse<T>::value, "You must use specialization!");
};

template
struct Foo<TheAnswer>{
    static constexpr int i = 42;
};
//...
```

Хочется этот `AlwaysFalse` как-то обобщить, чтобы можно было использовать в любой жизненной ситуации.

```
#define DEPENDENT_FALSE(arg) //????

template<class T>
struct Foo{
    static_assert(DEPENDENT_FALSE(T), "You must use specialization!");
};

template<int i>
struct Bar{
    static_assert(DEPENDENT_FALSE(i), "You must use specialization!");
};
```

У меня никак не выходит единообразно передавать `arg` куда-нибудь. Пробовал `decltype(arg)`, не работает если `arg` тип. Пробовал `someConstexprHelper<arg>()`, нужно писать перегрузки для всех возможных типов. Пробовал `sizeof(arg)`, но msvc не считает это за использование если `arg` не тип.

В распоряжении есть только С++11

Comment: А вариант с `template<class T> struct Foo;` не рассматривался? Сообщение об ошибке будет конечно не такое четкое, но зато в нем могут быть перечислены доступные (но не подошедшие) специализации.

Comment: @VTT, это было первое что я сделал. Но люди, которые могут от меня что-то требовать, потребовали `static_assert` :(

Answer (score 3):

Возможно, подойдет вариант с `sizeof`, т.к. `sizeof` умеет работать как с типом, так и с объектом.

```
template<class arg>
struct AlwaysFalse : std::false_type{};


#define DEPENDENT_FALSE(arg) AlwaysFalse<decltype(sizeof(arg))>::value

template<class T>
struct Foo{
    static_assert(DEPENDENT_FALSE(T), "You must use specialization!");
};

template<int i>
struct Bar{
    static_assert(DEPENDENT_FALSE(i), "You must use specialization!");
};
```

Конечно же, передаваемый в шаблон тип должен быть завершенным, если нет специализации для данного типа.

Comment: Пробовал. На [gcc](http://cpp.sh/5gbzh) все работает как надо, но вот [msvc](http://rextester.com/PUF64166) не считает применеие `sizeof`за использование параметра

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb а так: http://rextester.com/UZDO73477 ?

Comment: Действительно работает. А почему можете объяснить? Мне непонятно почему `sizeof(arg)` за использование параметра не считается, а `decltype(sizeof(arg))` считается

P.S. Если не возражаете, внес конечный код в ответ.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb не знаю. Я попробовал с decltype - заработало )))

Comment: Плохо, C++ это не тот язык, который можно изучать экспериментами.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb я считаю, что вариант с sizeof должен работать. Возможно, я не прав. Но если я прав, то в таком случае только эксперименты и остаются.

Comment: Вариант с "голым" sizeof на zapcc также не работает.

Comment: Извиняюсь что снял птицу, но на en so [пояснили](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51523965/template-dependent-false), что так работать не должно

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb sizeof, однако, является value-dependent, поэтому вариант без decltype не знаю почему не заводится в msvc.

Answer (score 0):

Решение на С++17, которе мне не подходит из за компилятора:

```
template<auto>
constexpr bool dependentFalseHelper(){
    return false;
}
template<class>
constexpr bool dependentFalseHelper(){
    return false;
}

#define DEPENDENT_FALSE(arg) (dependentFalseHelper<arg>())
```

Answer (score 0):

По-моему обобщить можно достаточно легко, стоит только сделать шаблон с неопределенным количеством аргументов для пачки типов и пачки величин:

```
template<typename ... x_Type> constexpr inline bool
AlwaysFalse(void) { return false; }

template<typename x_Val, x_Val ... x_val> constexpr inline bool
AlwaysFalseV(void) { return false; }

template<typename T> struct
Foo1
{
    static_assert(AlwaysFalse<T>(), "You must use specialization!");
};

template<typename ... T> struct
Foo2
{
    static_assert(AlwaysFalse<T ...>(), "You must use specialization!");
};

template<int x> struct
Foo3
{
    static_assert(AlwaysFalseV<int, x>(), "You must use specialization!");
};

template<int ... x> struct
Foo4
{
    static_assert(AlwaysFalseV<int, x ...>(), "You must use specialization!");
};
```

Comment: Так я хотел все это спрятать за макрос, чтобы не думать что использовать `AlwaysFalse` или `AlwaysFalseV`. Именно с этим проблемы

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb А зачем прятать за макрос? Макрос тут не сделает код короче и не устранит дублирование (которого и нет).

Comment: Можно и не под макрос. Суть в том, чтобы использовать всегда одно и то же выражение для получения `false`. Независимо от того, что подно на вход. Вот с С++17 у меня так получислось. Пиши себе `DEPENDENT_FALSE(x)`, а компилятор пусть сам разбирается что такое `x`